# How to load google or custom fonts in emails

Tags: html-email, webfonts, email-templates

I am trying to add fonts in my html email template but not any google font and custom font works.

I am using these methods to load fonts.

```
//Method 1

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalnia&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

//Method 2
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalnia&display=swap');
```

Can anyone clear which fonts will work for mail templates.

I am trying to add fonts in my html email template but not any google font and custom font works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom fonts support is related to each individual email client. You can check Can I Email’s support page for `@font-face`: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/

[image: Can I email… @font-face]